# Why are none of my if-statements executing?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
thirty_day_months = [4, 6, 9, 11]
thirtyone_day_months = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]
other_months = [2]
current_month = 1
current_day = 1

max_days = 0
if current_month > 12:
    current_month -= 12
print(current_month)
if current_month in thirty_day_months:
    if current_day > 30:
        current_day = 30
        max_days = 30
elif current_month in thirtyone_day_months:
    if current_day > 31:
        current_day = 31
        max_days = 31
elif current_month in other_months:
    if current_day > 28:
        current_day = 28
        max_days = 28
print(max_days)
```

The if-statements are supposed to assign a value to the "max_days" variable based on the value of the "current_month" variable. With a value of 14, current_month is correctly being assigned and printing "2". However, it seems that none of the if-statements following it are executing, regardless of the value of current_month.
I have tried using input() for current_month and current_day which didn't change anything.
The if-statements seem pretty simple to me but I am utterly lost as to what is going wrong here.

I have tried using values of 1 through 14. for current_month
I have double-checked the types of both current_month and a value from thirty_day_months list and they are both 'int' type.

I was expecting the program to read the value of current_month, check if the value is contained in any of the x_day_months lists (it should be as any value will be 1-12) and then print the maximum amount of days in that month.

Comment: Each of your if statements only sets max_days if the current_day is too large, as that is inside the _inner_ if statements of each block.

Comment: And all you need to set is `max_days`.  After that, you can say `if current_day > max_days:` / `current_day = max_days`.  And by the way, the Python `calendar` module includes a `monthrange` function that returns the number of days in the month.

Comment: Notwithstanding other comments/answers I can't help wondering how *current_month -= 12* helps when, for example, *current_month == 99* Also, shouldn't you be considering the year when figuring out *max_days* for February?

Comment: @DarkKnight I actually spotted the same thing a little bit after making this post and changed it to a while loop. As a second-year CS student, I'm still working on getting all the silly mistakes out of my system.

Answer (score 0):

As [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442918/max) pointed out [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76082876/why-are-none-of-my-if-statements-executing#comment134179863_76082876), your logic for determining the value for `max_days` is only ever run when both the outer and the respective inner if-condition are met. In other words for your implementation, if `current_day` exceeds a given threshold. Whenever the value isn't bigger, none of the statements populating the `current_days` variable are reached.

So

```py
thirty_day_months = [4, 6, 9, 11]
current_month = 4
current_day = 1

max_days = 0
if current_month > 12:
    current_month -= 12
print(current_month)
if current_month in thirty_day_months:
    print("Current month has 30 days.")
    if current_day > 30:
        print("Current day is larger than possible.")
        current_day = 30
        max_days = 30
# ..
print(max_days)
```

Running this would give you:

```
4
Current month has 30 days.
0
```

---

To get what you seem to be going for, just move the assignment of max_days out of the inner if-clause, i.e.:

```py
# ..
if current_month in thirty_day_months:
    max_days = 30
    if current_day > 30:
        current_day = 30
# ..
```

Rewriting the cases like this will assign the value in every case you're handling.

---

An additional note: if you are running on Python 3.10 or newer, consider looking into Python's [match expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#match-statements). They'll allow you to express the logic behind your outer if-elif blocks in a more idiomatic and elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

There are existing responses pointing out that why your code doesn't work. But your code really doesn't achieve its intended purpose even if someone tried to fix it.

Your method is not the correct way to achieve your intended purpose.

What is your purpose? Given a month expressed as a number, return the number of days in that month.

It's easy, see, just store the number of days as a `list`, and use list indexing to retrieve the value.

```
MAXDAYS = [
    31, 29, 31,
    30, 31, 30,
    31, 31, 30,
    31, 30, 31
]
```

Now how to get the number of days a month can have using `MAXDAYS`? Just use `MAXDAYS[month]` to get the number of days. Note `month` must be an `int`. And Python uses 0 based indexing, so if you want to retrieve the number of days of January, use `MAXDAYS[0]` instead of `MAXDAYS[1]`.

Now to increase reusability, wrap your code in a function.

```
MAXDAYS = [
    31, 29, 31,
    30, 31, 30,
    31, 31, 30,
    31, 30, 31
]

def get_maxdays(month):
    return MAXDAYS[month-1]
```

Usage example:

```
for i in range(1, 13):
    print(f'Month: {i}, Max_days: {get_maxdays(i)}')
```

```
Month: 1, Max_days: 31
Month: 2, Max_days: 29
Month: 3, Max_days: 31
Month: 4, Max_days: 30
Month: 5, Max_days: 31
Month: 6, Max_days: 30
Month: 7, Max_days: 31
Month: 8, Max_days: 31
Month: 9, Max_days: 30
Month: 10, Max_days: 31
Month: 11, Max_days: 30
Month: 12, Max_days: 31
```